# Object could not be added to the module. Only classes extending RealmObject or implementing RealmModel, which are part of this project, can be added

Tags: android, android-studio, realm

2020-07-06T16:16:44.900+0700 [ERROR] [system.err] error: Object could not be added to the module. Only classes extending RealmObject or implementing RealmModel, which are part of this project, can be added.
2020-07-06T16:16:45.018+0700 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
Object could not be added to the module. Only classes extending RealmObject or implementing RealmModel, which are part of this project, can be added.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQZj9.png)

Comment: Have you missed adding  extend RealmObject or implement RealmModel to any of your Realm model class? Verify once.

Comment: No, i added it first, idk what was the problem, but I just recreated my project and it's work for me.